CRichEditCtrl control Hyperlink color change
I have derived a class from CRichEditCtrl and the control contains multiple hyperlinks.
While every thing works as expected, customer wants to change the color of the hyperlinks to red. I tried many things, yet the hyperlink still shows in blue color.
Here is the code that fails:
for (int nLstCnt = 0; nLstCnt < nListCount; nLstCnt++)
{
    MESSAGELIST& objMsgList = m_arrMessageList[nLstCnt];
    SetSel(objMsgList.nStartPos + 1, objMsgList.nStartPos + objMsgList.strFormatString.GetLength() - 1);
    CHARFORMAT2 cf;
    memset(&cf, 0, sizeof(CHARFORMAT2));
    cf.cbSize = sizeof(CHARFORMAT2);
    cf.dwMask = CFM_LINK | CFM_COLOR;
    cf.dwEffects = CFE_LINK;
    cf.crTextColor = RGB(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
    SetSelectionCharFormat(cf);
}

It feels like if I use CFM_LINK, CFM_COLOR does not work.
Do I am missing something? Any help will be appreciated.
